# Compute data from a specific csv column in java

Tags: java, csv

I know that this kind of question has already been treated on this forum, but I didn't find the correct answer I liked. I have a csv file with 2 columns, I'd like to compute the sum the the second column (value column) of my file. These are my csv file and my code example :
file.csv

```
## Date ##     ## Value##
Status OK
12/12/2014          2
13/12/2014          5
14/12/2014          0
15/12/2014          3
Status KO
16/12/2014          5
17/12/2014          0
17/12/2014          7
17/12/2014          1
```

This class display just the column without the header (value). I like to make the sum of these elemnts (2+5+0+3+5+0+7+1)

```
public class LectureCSV {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String csvFile = "C:/Users/Downloads/file.csv";

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ';');
        String[] col;
        while ((col = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            if (!col[1].startsWith("valeur")) {
                System.out.println(col[1]);
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LectureCSV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody, i've got the answer to my question. it was quite easy !

```
public class LectureCSV {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String csvFile = "C:/Users/.../Downloads/file.csv";

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), ';');
        String[] col;
        float res = 0;
        while ((col = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            try {
                res = res + Float.parseFloat(col[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LectureCSV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you're already printing the values, why not just keep a count and add to it rather than print.

When you reach the end you can just print the sum.

Comment: thank you for your answer. now I can just print my column values. I didn't understand what you suggest. can you give me a peace of code please ?

Comment: Rather than call System.out.println, just add the value to a counter.